# SQLite3 in python - can't output

Tags: sqlite

I'm having an issue with SQL in python, I am simply creating a table and I want to print it out. I'm confused D: I am using python 3.x

```
import sqlite3 


print ("-" * 80)
print ("-                        Welcome to my Address Book                     -")
print ("-" * 80)


new_db = sqlite3.connect('C:\\Python33\\test.db')
c = new_db.cursor()


c.execute('''CREATE TABLE Students
(student_id text,
student_firstname text,
student_surname text,
student_DOB date,
Form text)
''')

c.execute('''INSERT INTO Students
          VALUES ('001', 'John','Doe', '12/03/1992', '7S')''')
new_db.commit()
new_db.close()



input("Enter to close")
```

Comment: Confused about what exactly? How to `print`? How to run a `SELECT` query?

Comment: I'm confused on how to print the table!

Comment: What's what you already wrote in the question. Please be more specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
firstname = "John"
surname   = "Foo"
c.execute("SELECT * FROM Students WHERE student_firstname LIKE ? OR student_surname LIKE ? ", [firstname, surname])
 while True:
    row = c.fetchone()
    if row == None:
        break# stops while loop if there is no more lines in table
    for column in row: #otherwise print line from table
            print col, " "
```

output should be:

```
001 John Doe 12/03/1992 7S
```

and any other row from table that contain first name `John` **OR** surname `Foo`